# How to solve 'Nonetype object has no attribute replace_with()' error in vscode while converting html to docx file?

Tags: python, html, google-chrome, visual-studio-code, translation

While converting html file to docx file using the below code, I am getting 'Nonetype object has no attribute replace_with()' error, when I was extracting the text from tags and replacing it with it's translation in any other language.

```
html = open("file_name.html").read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
tags = soup.find_all(["p","ul","ol","h1","h2","h3","h4","h5","h6"])
translator=Translator()
def callcon(t, tag):
  
for i in range(0, len(t)):
    if type(t[i])== NavigableString:

      translation=translator.translate(t[i],dest="af").text
      new_text = tag.find(text=str(t[i])).replace_with(translation)
     
      
    else:
      callcon(t[i].contents,tag)
for tag in tags:
 
  callcon(tag.contents, tag)
  
with open("file_name.html", "wb") as f_output:
    f_output.write(soup.prettify("utf-8"))
```

Please provide me with a solution for it.

Comment: that means that `tag.find(text=str(t[i]))` is returning None because it doesn't exist.  And `None` has no `replace_with` method.

Comment: Yes I know that, But how to resolve it?

Comment: I think it is not taking nested list, so do you any solution for it to make the code run and not give error?

Answer (score 0):

that means that tag.find(text=str(t[i])) is returning None because it doesn't exist. And None has no replace_with method

Just check the results of the `find_all` call and if it's None move on to the next iteration.

```
html = open("file_name.html").read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
tags = soup.find_all(["p","ul","ol","h1","h2","h3","h4","h5","h6"])
translator=Translator()
def callcon(t, tag):
  
for i in range(0, len(t)):
    if type(t[i])== NavigableString:
      translation=translator.translate(t[i],dest="af").text
      found = tag.find(text=str(t[i]))
      if found is not None:
          new_text = found.replace_with(translation)
    else:
      callcon(t[i].contents,tag)
for tag in tags:
  callcon(tag.contents, tag)
  
with open("file_name.html", "wb") as f_output:
    f_output.write(soup.prettify("utf-8"))
```

Comment: If I am running my above code on google colab, it is not giving any error and on vscode it is, can you tell why it's happening so?

Comment: The code which you gave is just skipping that paticular part and not translating it, do you have any other alternative code, which will not skip any part and translate the whole file.

Comment: @ZalakGandhi  It only skips that part if it doesn't exist.  You can't translate nothing, so I don't really know what you are asking for.

Comment: The code which you gave is skipping few paragraphs also.

Comment: If something is being skipped that is there it isn't my code that is skipping it.  I have no way to check which part is though because I don't have anything to test it on